# Json to pojo unmarshaler with polymorph classes for android

Tags: android, json, polymorphism

I am having a problem with rest and android, 
the problem is I have a transport object in example a class Human, which is extended by Male and Female, I want to use  json as transport for the human object.
if I use standard serialized objects, i would usually do

```
if(human instanceof Male.class){}
else if(human instance of Female.class){}
else{ throw new RuntimeException("incorrect class")}
```

how do I implement this in android with rest?
I've seen that Gson and Jaskson  which do not support polymorphism,
on the server side we're using Apache CXF for rest, with jax-rs annotations 
Ideas/previous experiences??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any automatic way to perform de-serialization, but one solution is to use a "[duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)" parser for your JSON.

Assume the following

```
class Human {
    public Human(JSONObject jo) {
        // Parse out common json elements
    }
}

class Male {
    private boolean hasMaleParts;
    public Male(JSONObject jo) {
        super(jo);
        // Parse out male only parts
    }
}

class Female {
    private boolean hasFemaleParts;
    public Female(JSONObject jo) {
        super(jo);
        // Parse out female only parts
    }
}
```

With these three classes, somewhere in your network access code, have a method which types your returned JSON and returns the appropriate object.

```
public Human typeJson(JSONObject jo) {
    if(jo.hasBoolean(hasMaleParts))
        return new Male(jo);
    else if(jo.hasBoolean(hasFemaleParts))
        return new Female(jo);
    else
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to determine data type");
}
```

In this example `hasMaleParts` and `hasFemaleParts` are arbitrary boolean flags, however, in many instances you could (more properly) type it using identifying attributes. So, if you were trying to distinguish between `Motorcycle` and `Car`, you might check `number_of_wheels`.